# Terminal velocity of mentos

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, drag

If somebody throws a mentos downwards (vertically) faster than the terminal velocity of a mentos, from the height at which the terminal velocity is reached from a falling mentos, will the mentos hit the ground below faster than a falling mentos or slower, or at the same speed?

Comment: The terminal velocity is never reached.

Comment: So the mentos will be travelling _below_ terminal velocity, or _above_ terminal velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentos thrown faster than terminal velocity will experience greater drag until it once again has terminal velocity (note - terminal velocity is only ever *approached* asymptotically, but we can decide to call "close enough"="equal")

If one thing is going faster than another for a while, after which they are traveling at the same speed, then the faster thing will have gotten ahead - and if they end up traveling at the same speed, it will not lose the head start.

So the one that is thrown down faster will hit the ground first.

Here is a picture to help visualize (I made up the numbers... but terminal velocity for both is 1 m/s here)

[image]

As you can see, the red Mentos (the one that was thrown down with extra velocity) gets ahead of the blue Mentos during the initial phase - once they are traveling at the same velocity, they keep a constant distance.

If you want to play with the Excel file used to generate the above plot, it can be found at [this link](http://www.floris.us/physicsSE/mentos.xlsx)

Answer (score 1):

The terminal velocity is by definition the velocity for which the gravitational force is equal to the friction force of a falling body. As the friction force grow with speed (linearly for laminar flow, quadratically for turbulent flow) an object going faster that the terminal velocity will have his friction force bigger than the gravitational force and thus will decelerate until it reach the terminal velocity while an object going slower will accelerate until it reach the terminal velocity (for which the forces compensates and the acceleration is 0).

Once you throw your object with a speed bigger than the terminal velocity it will slow down. Knowing if it will have reached the terminal velocity when it hit the ground depend of the initial velocity and the type of friction the body experience...